# How to display one Column after another and allow to scroll screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to develop app that with two blocks. Every block is column one after another. If content if not fitted to screen scrolls should be appeared.

I wrote next app. But problem that I can't get scrolling work and getting bottom overflow. I tried to wrap all in `SingleChildScrollView` but it wont work.

[image]

Here is my copy-paste code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'aaaa'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  late String title;
  MyHomePage({required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 252, 234),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                child: SizedBox( // emulation of block with fixed size content.
                  height: 450,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),

          // flex: 5,
          Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                  Text("Hello"),
                ],
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use listView and column with shrink wrap. or SingleChildScrollView or SliverList

Comment: Wrapping the `Column` in a `SingleChildScrollview` does work for me. Wrap the `column` that contains the `text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're adding the `SingleChildScrollView()` in the incorrect places.
You have to add it in:

```dart
Container(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 252, 234),
```

and also in your second `Column()`.

You can try:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'aaaa'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  late String title;
  MyHomePage({required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 252, 234),
                  margin:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    // emulation of block with fixed size content.
                    height: 450,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),

          // flex: 5,
          Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  late String title;
  MyHomePage({required this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 252, 234),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                child: SizedBox( // emulation of block with fixed size content.
                  height: 450,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),

          // flex: 5,
          Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 150),
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: [
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                    Text("Hello"),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change column in your second Bloc to Listview then wrap it with Flexible instead of Expanded widget